# Underline animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to recreate the animation on description and review [here](http://demo.uix.store/sober/product/lace-up-sneakers/?single_product_style=style-3).
The underline animates from right to left when the link is unclicked the underline animates from left to right before it disappears.

```css
a {
  color:#00f;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
a:after {
  width: 0;
  display:block;
  background:#00f;
  height:3px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  content:"";
}
a:hover {
  color:#00f;
}
a:hover:after {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click first</a>
<a href="#">Click second</a>
```

Comment: You'll find the answer if you fire up the devtools on your reference. They use `position: absolute` with `left: 0; right: 0;` which gives the full width. Removing any of those gives you an animation to an opposite direction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Use `position` on the pseudoelement. Add `position: relative` to `a`, and `position: absolute` to `:after`.
2. Position the pseudoelement using `bottom` and `right`. This means the line originates from the right side.
3. On hover/click, add the `left` property. This makes the line span the full width. The width grows from `0` to `100%` from left to right.

When you 'unhover' or click again, `left` is removed, and the line originates from the right again, so the width decreases in that direction.

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  $('a').not(this).removeClass('underline');
  $(this).toggleClass('underline');
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  width: 0;
  background: #00f;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: 0;
}

a.underline:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click first</a>
<a href="#">Click second</a>
```

Comment: the animation in the link above takes place when the link is hover but also when the other link is clicked. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: when you click on the first link and then on the second link you have both link hovered . How could i unhover the first link when the second link is click with the animation

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you want a HTML/CSS only solution:

```css
a {
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a span:after {
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #00f;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  float: right;
}

a span:focus {
  color: #00f;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label input {
  display: none;
}

label input:checked + span:after, label input + span:hover:after  {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

label input:checked + span {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="link" />
    <span>
      Click first
    </span>
  </label>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="link" />
    <span>
      Click second
    </span>
  </label>
</a>
```

Comment: yeah I saw that but adding tags says nothing about a wanted solution.

Comment: [sol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46887216/6225838) is also a no-JS (HTML/CSS only) solution if `a:hover:after` is simply changed to `a:hover:after, a:focus:after`...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following. Just use a class to set style.

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('start');
  $(this).toggleClass('start');
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
a {
  color:#00f;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
a:after {
  width: 0;
  display:block;
  background:#00f;
  height:3px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  content:"";
  float:right;
}
a:hover {
  color:#00f;
}
a.start:after {
  width: 100%;
}
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click first</a>
<a href="#">Click second</a>
```

Comment: this seems like the correct answer. wth was it downvoted ?

Comment: @Hamzaouiii May be because I used `jQuery` for this.

Comment: but he has javascript and jquery in his tags.!

Comment: May be  some hypocrite did not read the question. It needs to work on `click` action.

Comment: OP is high. the underline in the website he mentioned is not triggered by a click, but only with a hover.

Comment: I think there is a mistake, he needs it from right to left. and I have fixed it now.

Comment: Hamzaouiii  and  Rejith R Krishnan you're both right the animation takes places when the link is hover but also when an another link is click